Bibliography: citing editor of collection
How can I indicate the editor(s) of a collection with the features as shown in the following figure?

So I need there to be a "(Hg.)" (German for ed.) after the editor’s last name and the superposed edition number before the year. You can try it out with the following code (figuring different literature from that shown above).
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}%
  \setunit*{\addspace=\space}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hg\adddot},
  editors = {Hgg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}
  }%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Abeille,
  title     = {La grande grammaire du français},
  publisher = {Actes Sud},
  date      = {2021},
  address   = {Arles},
  volume    = 2,
  editor    = {Abeillé, Anne and Godard, Danièle},
}
@incollection{Combettes,
  author    = {Combettes, Bernard},
  title     = {Le discours rapporté et les incises},
  crossref  = {Abeille},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Abeille}, \cite{Combettes}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Have you tried citing the ‘collection’ (@collection), i.e. all the bibliographic units that are part of the whole and not just the individual part you are citing, in a separate entry, and then referencing it from each of the parts (@incollection) using the crossref field? Check the < >-ext styles. https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext

As discussed in the comments, you want the citexref feature of the biblatex-ext styles to produce these "short citations" also in the bibliography. We can then combine this with the ideas from Add translator info in cite command and BibLaTex - mark editor in cite and bibligraphy (labelname) to get the "Hg."/"ed." after editor names also in citations.
Together we have
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  innameidem=true,
  citexref=true,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\slash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\adddot\space}

\newbibmacro{cite:labelname}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{editor}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{translator}
         {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
         {}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}%
          \csuse{extblx@citedelim@\blx@delimcontext @inner@open}}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}%
       \csuse{extblx@citedelim@\blx@delimcontext @inner@open}}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}%
  \setunit*{\addspace=\space}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL: <\url{#1}>}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hg\adddot},
  editors = {Hgg\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\printorigdate}}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}
  }%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
       \global\clearfield{edition}%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\sernumdelim}%
       \printfield{number}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@collection{Abeille,
  title     = {La grande grammaire du français},
  publisher = {Actes Sud},
  date      = {2021},
  address   = {Arles},
  volume    = 2,
  editor    = {Abeillé, Anne and Godard, Danièle},
}
@incollection{Combettes,
  author    = {Combettes, Bernard},
  title     = {Le discours rapporté et les incises},
  crossref  = {Abeille},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Abeille,Combettes}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


